# process.env's are undefined - NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, environment-variables, nestjs

I've decided to write here because I've ran out of ideas. I have a NestJS app in which I use env's - nothing unusual. But something strange happens when I want to use them. I also have my own parser of these values which returns them in a convenient object - that's the first file:

**env.ts**

```
const parseStringEnv = (name: string) => {
  const value: string = process.env[name];

  if (!value) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid env ${name}`);
  }

  return value;
};

const parseIntEnv = (name: string) => {
  const value: string = process.env[name];

  const int: number = parseInt(value);

  if (isNaN(int)) {
    throw new Error(`Invalid env ${name}`);
  }

  return int;
};

const parseBoolEnv = (name: string) => {
  const value: string = process.env[name];

  if (value === "false") {
    return false;
  }

  if (value === "true") {
    return true;
  }

  throw new Error(`Invalid env ${name}`);
};

const parseMongoString = (): string => {
  const host = parseStringEnv("DATABASE_HOST");
  const port = parseStringEnv("DATABASE_PORT");
  const user = parseStringEnv("DATABASE_USER");
  const pwd = parseStringEnv("DATABASE_PWD");
  const dbname = parseStringEnv("DATABASE_NAME");

  return `mongodb://${user}:${pwd}@${host}:${port}/${dbname}?authSource=admin&ssl=false`;
};

export const env = {
  JWT_SECRET: parseStringEnv("JWT_SECRET"),
  PORT_BACKEND: parseIntEnv("PORT_BACKEND"),
  CLIENT_HOST: parseStringEnv("CLIENT_HOST"),
  ENABLE_CORS: parseBoolEnv("ENABLE_CORS"),
  MONGO_URI: parseMongoString(),
};

export type Env = typeof env;
```

I want to use it for setting port on which the app runs on and also the connection parameters for Mongoose:

**In main.ts:**

```
<rest of the code>
await app.listen(env.PORT_BACKEND || 8080);
<rest of the code>
```

Now, the magic starts here - the app starts just fine when ONLY `ConfigModule` is being imported. It will also start without `ConfigModule` and with `require('doting').config()` added. When I add `MongooseModule`, the app crashes because it can't parse env - and the best thing is that exception thrown has nothing to do with env's that are used to create `MONGO_URI`!! I'm getting "`Invalid env JWT_SECRET`" from my parser.

**In app.module.ts**

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";
import { MongooseModule } from "@nestjs/mongoose";

import { AppController } from "./app.controller";
import { env } from "./common/env";

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(env.MONGO_URI), //WTF?
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I've honestly just ran out of ideas what could be wrong. The parser worked just fine in my last project (but I haven't used Mongoose so maybe that's what causes issues). Below is my .env file template.

```
JWT_SECRET=
ENABLE_CORS=
PORT_BACKEND=
DATABASE_HOST=
DATABASE_PORT=
DATABASE_USER=
DATABASE_PWD
DATABASE_NAME=
CLIENT_HOST=
```

Thanks for everyone who has spent their time trying to help me ;)

Comment: I'd say don't use `process.env` directly like this. Instead, delegate the loading/parser/validation to some module like `@nestjs/config` (follow this: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#configuration) or `nestjs-config`. It would be pretty easy to load any env. var with them

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it but I wanted to use my own parser. Anyway, I'll give this a try since mine is not working. Thanks for comment!

Comment: Did you try to add the envFilePath in the ConfigModule.forRoot configuration ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What's happening is you're importing `env.ts` *before* the ConfigModule has imported and set the variables in your `.env` file.

This is why calling `require('dotenv').config()` works.  Under the hood, that's what the ConfigModule is doing for you.  However, your call to `ConfigModule.forRoot` is happening *after* you import `env.ts`, so the `.env` file hasn't been imported yet and those variables don't yet exist.

I would highly recommend you take a look at [custom configuration files](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#custom-configuration-files), which handles this for you the "Nest way":

From the Nest docs, but note that you could also use the `env.ts` file you already have:

```
// env.ts
export default () => ({
  // Add your own properties here however you'd like
  port: parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000,
  database: {
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT, 10) || 5432
  }
});
```

And then modify your AppModule to the following.  Note that we're using the forRootAsync so that we can get a handle to the ConfigService and grab the variable from that.

```
// app.module.ts
import configuration from './common/env';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      load: [configuration],
    }),
    //  
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        uri: configService.get<string>('MONGO_URI'),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    });
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

As an alternative, you could also just call `require('dotenv').config()` inside your `env.ts` file at the top, but you'll miss out on all the ConfigModule helpers like dev/prod `.env` files.

Comment: I've used ConfigService like you recommended and it works like a charm ;) Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 7):

By using registerAsync of JWT module and read process.env inside useFactory method worked for me

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.registerAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
        signOptions: { expiresIn: 3600 },
      }),
    })
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
```

Comment: thank you. your solution helped me, without any ConfigModule (isGlobal: true) etc. 
I even consoled secret from useFactore, and it is really works right

Answer (score 2):

In my case just need to replace the order import module.

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";
import { MongooseModule } from "@nestjs/mongoose";

import { AppController } from "./app.controller";
import { env } from "./common/env"; // call process.env.xxx here > undefined

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
    }), // process.env.xxx must be called after this line
    MongooseModule.forRoot(env.MONGO_URI),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

so fix

```
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { ConfigModule } from "@nestjs/config";
// should place this at very first line
const envModule = ConfigModule.forRoot({
   isGlobal: true,
})

import { MongooseModule } from "@nestjs/mongoose";

import { AppController } from "./app.controller";
import { env } from "./common/env";

@Module({
  imports: [
    envModule,
    MongooseModule.forRoot(env.MONGO_URI),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I downgraded @types/node to be the same version as my node version. Could be a hint.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).